# Pass an input variable to PHP using AJAX, but not with POST

Tags: php, ajax, variables

My form is like the one above:

```
<form id="calculator">
<input type="text" name="height" id="height"/>
<input type="text" name="inferiorPanel" id="inferiorPanel" readonly />
<button type="button" onclick="calculatePanels();">
</form>
```

Jquery script is the next one:

```
function calculatePanels() {
     var Height = document.forms["calculator"]["height"].value;

     $.ajax({
                url: "includes/inferiorPanel.php",
                success: function(result){
            $("#inferiorPanel").val(result);
            }});
}
```

And PHP code from inferiorPanel.php is:

```
<?php
$height = ????; 

        switch ($height) {

            case ($height > 0 && $height <= 1845):
            echo 615;
            break;

            case ($height > 1845 && $height <= 1980):
            echo 495;
            break;

            case ($height > 1980 && $height <= 2100):
            echo 495;
            break;

            case ($height > 2100 && $height <= 2220):
            echo 495;
            break;

            case ($height > 2220 && $height <= 2340):
            echo 615;
            break;

            case ($height > 2340 && $height <= 2460):
            echo 615;
            break;

            case ($height > 2460 && $height <= 2475):
            echo 495;
            break;

            case ($height > 2475 && $height <= 2595):
            echo 615;
            break;

            case ($height > 2595 && $height <= 2715):
            echo 615;
            break;

            case ($height > 2715 && $height <= 2835):
            echo 615;
            break;

            case ($height > 2835 && $height <= 2955):
            echo 615;
            break;

            case ($height > 2955 && $height <= 3000):
            echo 615;
            break;
}
```

My question is:
How to pass the variable `height` in PHP without using `POST` on Ajax, in order to show the result in input `inferiorPanel`?

I do not want to use `<input type="submit" />` because will refresh the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Page refreshes not because you use `$_POST`, but because your code is incomplete.

Here what you need to do (you have `jquery`, so use it):

1. Remove `onclick` from `button`, remove `<button>`, add `submit`:

   ```
   <form id="calculator">
       <input type="text" name="height" id="height"/>
       <input type="text" name="inferiorPanel" id="inferiorPanel" readonly />
       <input type="submit" name="Name" value="Value">
   </form>
   ```
2. Bind a handler to submit event of your form

   ```
   $( "#calculator" ).submit(function() {
       var Height = $( "#height" ).val();

       $.ajax({
           url: "includes/inferiorPanel.php",
           data: { height: Height},
           type: "POST",
           success: function(result){
               $("#inferiorPanel").val(result);
           }
       });

       // simple way to prevent default action of form submission:
       return false;
   } );
   ```
3. On server side:

   ```
   <?php
   $height = $_POST['height']; 
   switch ($height) {
       // run your switch here
   }
   ?>
   ```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It worked perfectly with `submit`  thanks to `return false`.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `POST` without refreshing the page

```
 $.ajax({
     url: "includes/inferiorPanel.php",
     method: "POST",
     data : {'height' : Height},
     success: function(result){
         $("#inferiorPanel").val(result);
     }
 });
```

and in php :

```
<?php
    $height = $_POST['height'];
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify GET in the Ajax call and have height in the URL as follows

```
var height = $('#height').val();


 $.ajax({
        type        : 'GET', 
        url         : 'inferiorPanel.php?height=' + height,
```

Within your php you can just say if(isset($_GET['height']) $height = $_GET['height'];

Comment: Thanks. I went on POST although, with return false in order not to refresh the page. This was the purpose: not to refresh the page.

Comment: Its not whether you use GET or POST that matters. To avoid refreshing the page you need Ajax, no submits. As was pointer out by u_munder, you are ,missing the logic to fire the Ajax call - ie.button click (not submit)